# Ajax function to collect geoJSON FeatureCollection and then output popups onto leaflet map layer

Tags: ajax, maps, leaflet, geojson

I am trying to create an ajax function in which I use a form to pass a bbox value to a PHP script which then uses the bbox parameters to output a FeatureCollection back to the ajax callback.

From this I am using JSON.parse() and then trying to display the description part of each feature as a popup over its corresponding point.

I have spent countless hours trying to figure out what is going wrong in my code but I just can't seem to work it out.

Here is my HTML for the form:

```
<select name="bbox" id="bbox" onchange="ajaxrequest()">
  <option name="Select" value="Select">Please Select</option>
  <option name="Hampshire" value="-1.40,50,-1.39,51&format=geojson">Hampshire</option>
</select>
```

Here is my AJAX function:

```
function ajaxrequest()
{
    var bbox = document.getElementById("bbox").value;
    //alert(bbox);
    var request = new Ajax().sendRequest
        ('points.php',
            { method: 'GET',
              parameters: 'bbox=' + bbox,
              callback: resultsReturned }
        );
}
```

And here is the AJAX callback which contains the feature collection geoJSON in the response text:

```
function resultsReturned (xmlHTTP)
{
    //alert(xmlHTTP.responseText);
    var geojson = JSON.parse(xmlHTTP.responseText);

    for(var i=0; i<geojson.features.length; i++)
    {
        var layer = new L.geojson();
        layer.addData(geojson.features[i]);
    }
}
```

Would greatly appreciate it if someone could fill me in on how to finish this as it's killing me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Do you get a proper response? Can you show us the value of `xmlHTTP.responseText`?

Comment: Sure, I will show you a shortened version. 
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":["-1.4266","50.9168"]},"properties":{"id":"15","name":"Sanjha Restaurant","country":"England","region":"Hampshire","description":"Description"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":["-1.34532","50.9303"]},"properties":{"id":"16","name":"The Master Builder","country":"England","region":"Hampshire","description":"Description"}}]}

Comment: As you can see in the JS I have alerts testing the value before and after the AJAX call just to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this then:

```
function resultsReturned (xmlHTTP)
{
    var features = JSON.parse(xmlHTTP.responseText);
    L.geoJson(features).addTo(map);
}
```

(See http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html)

If you want to bind a popup to each feature:

```
function resultsReturned (xmlHTTP)
{
    var features = JSON.parse(xmlHTTP.responseText);
    L.geoJson(features, 
        { onEachFeature: 
              function(feature,layer) {
                  layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.description);
              }
        }).addTo(map);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From this I need to put an oneachfeature function that adds a popup with each features description to the map does that go straight underneath?

Comment: you can provide options to the geoJson constructor, yes. I've added an example how to add your onEachFeature option.

Comment: Approved your answer as it seems a more concise way than I achieved it. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**
I added this code to my init function. Please note the "null" as this is required so the AJAX callback can populate it.

```
layer = new L.GeoJSON( null,
    { onEachFeature: function(feature,layer)
        {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.description);
        }
    }).addTo(map);
```

My initial AJAX call function is the same as posted above and the AJAX response has been changed slightly to this:

```
function resultsReturned (xmlHTTP)
{
    //alert(xmlHTTP.responseText);
    var features = JSON.parse(xmlHTTP.responseText);

    for(var i=0; i<features.features.length; i++)
    {
        layer.addData(features.features[i]);
    }

}
```

Thanks for the help @flup for helping me understand the way the the coding works :)

Comment: Or you can simply provide the entire set of features to the constructor.